# My code is showing with the instructions on my browsers

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, safari, console, console.log

I am an absolute beginner. Yesterday I noticed my Visual studio code showed colors when I program and it translates to console on my browser but it’s all grey today and my code and instruction all translate to my browser like the picture. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcxmO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You're writing Javascript code in a plain HTML file, that won't work. You need to create a Javascript file or create a `<script>` tag and place the Javascript code there.